# How to modify a column value of a spark Data Frame based on condition in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to change an expression of a value based on condition
For Example suppose this is my DF:

```
 1             |  2.      |   
---------------------------
[a ,b]         |  7       
a              |  7
[1, a, b].     |  6
a              |  3
b              |  2
[a,b]          |  7
```

I want (if column 2 has value 7) then... each "a" in column 1 to be deleted. That's, if for example "a" is inside an array [a,b] i want the array to contain only b. And if its alone as a string and not inside an array then I want it to be empty.

The following data frame should be the result:

```
 1             |  2     |   
---------------------
[b]            |  7            
               |  7``
[1,a, b]       |  6
a              |  3
b              |  2
[,b]           |  7
```

**Summary: If in column 2 there is a '7' then delete "a" from column 1**

I tried to first explode the first column so that each value either in an array or a string alone is placed in different row. And then I want to delete the value of that column each time second column has value 7. But it didn't quite work out for me.

I realized there might be an easier way of doing a regular-expression-REPLACE which would turn each "a" to '  ' (an empty tab).  But how do I do a reg expression replace based on condition that second column has 7 as its value?

Comment: your example dataframes are unclear, could you do .show() on your sample data and then post here in the form of a table? it would ppl answer your question.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. I don't know how to edit or copy the data frame into here. If someone can help. It's just two columns separated by a vertical line